# How to mock a class in one script from another test script running the first

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, monkeypatching, python-unittest.mock

I have a class SQLES in a separate script, sqles.py, which is imported in main.py and comprises methods to read SQL data and set the results in the class instance.

I am now writing a test script, test_main.py, in which I want to define a mock SQLES class to be used transparently by main.py instead of the real SQLES. I am not testing SQLES itself, and the idea of the mock class is to include the same set of methods but return hard-coded lists of data rows.

I have searched for hours, but not one result on python/mock/etc explains how to set up this apparently very simple requirement. This is the test script (truncated for clarity) which I have prepared so far:

```
import unittest.mock

import main    # main.py script I wish to run with the mocked SQLES class

class MockSQLES: # Dummy class I wish main.py to instantiate and use instead of SQLES

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def init(self, logger, cmd_args_record, cmd_args_playback):
        return

    # Couple of specimen methods, to give an idea of what dummy SQL class does ..

    def get_exchange_rates(self):
        self.exchange_rates['GBP'] = [
            [ '2021-09-13', 0.722298 ],
            [ '2021-08-20', 0.734203 ]
        ]
        return

    def get_firms_names_other(self):
         self.firms_names_other[firm_id] = [
            [ 131, 'Acme Industries' ],
            [ 132, 'Acme Research'   ]
        ]
        return

           ::::

with unittest.mock.patch('main.SQLES') as MockSQLES:

    main.main()
```

But when I try running it, a debug print after the instance assigment:

```
   sql = SQLES()
```

shows that the resulting sql object has type unittest.mock.MagicMock rather than the MockSQLES I expected, and sure enough the methods in the latter are not being called.

So in summary, I would like to know how to fix this. Perhaps Mock is the wrong approach, and some other method (monkey patching? ) is better suited for this.

Also, I don't wish to tinker with the main.py script any more than can be avoided. (It's obvious how a mock SQL class could be used if main.py had a test flag or similar to create an instance of either SQLES or MockSQLES.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the mock class. When you performed this:

```
with unittest.mock.patch('main.SQLES') as MockSQLES:
```

The yielded response of the context manager `unittest.mock.patch` would be assigned to the [as clause](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__enter__) variable `MockSQLES`. So `MockSQLES` here isn't actually the mock class but is the yielded response of the patch. What you could try to do is:

```
with unittest.mock.patch('main.SQLES', MockSQLES) as mock_sql:
```

For reference of [unittest.mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), the 1st argument is the functionality to patch `SQLES` while the 2nd argument is the replacement `MockSQLES` as documented:

> ##### `unittest.mock.patch(target, new=DEFAULT, ...)`
>
> ... the **target** is patched with a **new** object

Make sure to also read about [Mocking Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-classes) for further reference.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Many thanks Niel!